# How to create bash script to do/undo setting locale with one alias?

Tags: locale, bash

How to create bash script (to make alias of it), doing this:

```
if LANG=en_US.UTF-8
then "unset LANG"
else "export LANG=en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: That's almost exactly what you need though it can't be a script that you run it can be a script your `source`/`.` or a function though.

Comment: The if condition can be `[[ $LANG == "en_US.UTF-8" ]]`

Comment: Convert this to a script, and then assign an alias to call the script? Also, is your intention to "toggle" `LANG`? Good luck.

Comment: @EtanReisner I tried this and it's not not working `if LANG=en_US.UTF-8; then unset LANG; else export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; fi`

Comment: @shellter yes, I want to toggle `LANG` in OS X

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks! it works!

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "almost exactly".

Comment: thanks for answers, `if [[ $LANG == "en_US.UTF-8" ]]; then unset LANG; else export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; fi` works!

Comment: Post that as an answer and accept it. (You can accept your own answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding

```
en() {
if [[ $LANG == "en_US.UTF-8" ]]
then unset LANG
else export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
fi
}
```

to `~/.bash_profile` works!

Comment: Add to `.bash_profile` instead (or don't use `[[...]]`); `.profile` should only include POSIX compatible code.